# Mapping models of same type to view instances

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-game-engine, inversion-of-control

I'm using [Strange IOC](http://strangeioc.github.io/strangeioc/TheBigStrangeHowTo.html) in my game, and I'm having trouble working out how to map Views to Models.

At game start, I create several enemy models. These models contain various stats used during operation (such as damage amounts, health, etc.). I operate on these stats using Commands. I then loop through all of my models in the Start command and create appropriate Views for them. Each `EnemyView` has an `EnemyMediator`, which should fire the Commands for managing AI.

I need a way of telling a `View` which `Model` instance they belong to. Strange IOC injection bindings are typically distinguished by type, or an optional additional identifier. All of my enemy models and views are the same type, so I have to use this identifier. The problem then comes when trying to actually inject the instances.

I initially tried giving each of my enemy models a GUID, and passing that to the `View` and `Mediator`, but the problem then comes from the fact that Strange IOC injection uses static injection criteria. Trying to apply my GUID in the `Inject` attributes raises a compiler error for obvious reasons.

This lead me to using `InjectionBinder.Injector.Inject()` to manually acquire bindings during my `Command`'s execution using the GUID. This works, but it's now adding a dependency on the injector that I shouldn't need, and I'm essentially using the injector as a Service Locator, and losing the benefits of injection.

The problem is, I don't know how to inject the specific model my `EnemyView` belongs to into the commands I fire, and therefore I'm stuck with Service Locator-style workarounds.

For reference, this: [image]

is the application structure I am trying to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to come up with one option.

For each enemy:

- Create the enemy model.
- Create a separate context for each enemy, and store the model in
  there.
- Create a mediation binding between the EnemyView type and the
  EnemyMediator type inside the enemy context.
- Create the enemy view from within the context.

The context will then create the enemy mediator and bind the enemy model into the enemy mediator.

The downside of this solution:

1. It leads to a *lot* of contexts, which bring along their own
   injection binders, etc.
2. It leads to heavy usage of cross-context
   bindings, potentially polluting that binding space. This could be
   fixed by modifying the Context to use a hierarchical lookup (which I
   may attempt to do later today) before looking in the cross-context
   binder.

Comment: Managed to get hierarchical bindings working, so many contexts are less undesirable than before. Would still like to know if there's a better way out there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct solution but this is how I work around this issue. I create a singleton model for all enemies. This model contains a dictionary where the key is the view.GetInstanceID() and the value is a class that holds the stats for that specific enemy.

```
public class EnemyModel : IEnemyModel
{
    // int is the id of the enemy's instance id in the view i.e. view.GetInstanceID()
    public IDictionary<int,Enemy> enemyDict {get;set;}

    public EnemyModel ()
    {
        enemyDict = new Dictionary<int,Enemy>();
    }
}

public class Enemy
{
    public bool  isDangerous = false;
    public float health = 1;
}
```

Comment: This is a solution I toyed with too, I quite like the idea of only injecting the information a component needs though, so the hierarchical model suited it better, but this is definitely a much faster and more intuitive system,

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem to solve and here is solution I came up with.

EnemyMediator has a refferance to to Enemy (but not injected, may be even private).
EnemyMediator needs to have some singleton game model  which as property current enemy;

Now when you create an enemies in some command you instantiate an enemies (Inject game model), you create model first and add it to currentEnemy value of game model. Now you instantiate view.

In PostConstruct method you read currentEnemy value form game model  and set it in Mediator.

When you fire a Signal/Event you add enemy as a parameter. Now command has information about a model.

I do not like adding model to mediator, but I haven't found better solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered your same doubts and questions while trying to understand where the  fit better inside IOC.
So, reading the documentation I read something like that "models are like Value Objects (VO)". 
So I came up with this solution that use the potential of Unity as well.
Here's my design with an example:

- I create a "EnemyModel" class that is a Monobehaviour and implement a generic IEnemyModel interface
- during the scene loading, inside the StartCommand of the context, I use AddComponent to add a EnemyModel to each EnemyView. The data for each EnemyModel are loaded from a file or database that describe the data properties of my scene.
- the mediator has a reference to the EnemyView and to the EnemyModel (through the interface)
- when a command is dispatched in the mediator (I use signals) the EnemyModel is passed as a parameter.
- in the command I have a reference to the data passed as a parameter so the command already knows the data to work with and it is actually working on the model.

I thinks it's better like that than passing some kind of ID and trying to resolve the data through a data manager or so. Also if EnemyModel is a monobehaviour attached to the EnemyView game object is easier to debug his values from the editor.

What do you think?